# loop not running until 2147483647

Tags: c

in my code, when I input numbers 1 and 2147483647, loop will only run until 113382. it should've run from 1 to 2147483647.

problem link(if anyone's interested):
https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=307

P.S: I am using codeblocks in windows 10

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
    long int L,H,t,l,h,j,k,m;
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%ld %ld",&L,&H);
        if(L == 0 && H == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if(L > H)
            {
                t = L;
                L = H;
                H = t;
            }
            long int maximum = 0,maximumindex;
            l = L;
            h = H;
            for(j = 0; L <= H;L++)
            {
                k = L;
                m = 0;
                do
                {
                    if(k % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        k = (3 * k) + 1;
                        m++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        k = k / 2;
                        m++;
                    }
                }
                while(k != 1);
                if(m > maximum)
                {
                    maximum = m;
                    maximumindex = L;

                }
                printf("%ld %ld\n",m,L);
            }
            printf("Between %ld and %ld, %ld generates the longest sequence of %ld values.\n",l,h,maximumindex,maximum);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apparently the behaviour of integer overflow (`2147483647+1` needs 32 bits) in your particular example is a silent wrap-around. The Standard does not mandate any specific behaviour: your program could as well *crash*, display the lyrics of the anthem of Spain, behave as you expect, ...

Comment: it seems your `long` are on 32 bits, use `unsigned long` and you will continue after 113382. But not sure enough for 2147483647, if you have `unsigned long long` on 64bits use them

Comment: out of that, what about to check `scanf` return 2 to know if the inputs are correct ? Your question remember me an other recent question

Comment: and if you expect a result better to remove `printf("%ld %ld\n",m,L);` or to do it only when L is a multiple of a big number

Comment: 32bits `unsigned long` is not enough, and 'stop' (even still running) before 1432000000, you need 64b integer (`uint64_t`)

Comment: But the problem i am trying to solve specifies that every number in the sequence between the two integers i input (suppose 1 and 20) should not be greater than 32bit or long data type. You can see it in the input section of the problem link i have given

Comment: it is not clear in the reference you cannot use longer numbers, the reference just say the largest value in the sequence stay on 32b, this is not the same. Else you have to modify your algorithm to use 32b int without overflow. The problem concerns **k*

Comment: So should i use more than 32bits?

Comment: ok. using `unsigned long long int` for every data type did the trick. but my program is extremely time consuming. a sequence between 1 to 10000000 takes about 10 secs to show the output. any ideas how to optimize it?

Comment: I put an answer, yes it does 1000000 per second. I know there was a question with the same algorithm recently but I still do not find it

Comment: I am not enough good in math to find an other algorithm, but your algo is very simple to paralyze doing a loop on each core you have. You are under Windows, I do under Linux I can give a proposal using *pthread* but you probably do not have

Answer (score 2):

Your problem indicates your `long` are on 32 bits.

You want to search up to 2147483647 which is the maximum signed integer on 32 bits.

In your code you have :

> ```
> for(j = 0; L <= H;L++)
> ```

using signed int on 32 bits when L is 2147483647 and you do `L++` you have an overflow with an undefined behavior (commonly L become larger negative int), and same later for *l* getting *L* value.

To avoid that you need to use at least unsigned integer on 32 bits.

Because of the math you use it is worst for *k*, that one need more than 32 bits, for it you need a larger type, for instance 64 bits (`int64_t` or `uint64_t`), this is why your program stops to print *k* never being 1

You probably placed `printf("%ld %ld\n",m,L);̀` to debug your code, but all these print are dramatic for the execution time, if you want to print do that when *L* is a multiple of a large number.

Using unsigned on 32 bits for all the variables except for *k* being an `int64_t` the result for 1 and 2147483647 is :

> Between 1 and 2147483647, 1674652263 generates the long longest sequence of 1008 values.

To not depend on the size of the `int` etc which are variable, use the types `uint32_t` and `int64_t`. For *scanf* and *printf* do not use `"%d"` etc but `"%"PRIu32` for `uint32_t` and `"%"PRId64` for `int64_t`  defined in `inttypes.h`

Comment: The overflow causes undefined behaviour (may or may not result in execution appearing to continue with `L` being `0` -- and did not in OP's case)

Comment: @M.M yes undefined behavior but 0 in practice :-), anyway I correct my answer, thank you

Comment: OK. I'd expect -2147483648 to be more common than 0, but we should try to avoid expectations in any case. OP experienced the loop breaking at 113382 instead (apparently)

Comment: @M.M *k* is the problem is OP case, when it overflow it seem OP get negative numbers and *k* do not reach 1 in a short time.

Comment: @M.M oh yes not 0, I had in head unsigned case

Comment: @M.M I updated, for *l* too. It is 'more complicated' for *k* but *k* overflows before *L* for sure. I know there was an other question about the same thing (or very similar) recently, but I cannot find it

Comment: Even using a larger unsigned type for `k`, there is still the possibility of "overflow" and producing incorrect results , I think the code is going to have to include some upper bound check on `k` before doing the `*3` to at least let you know that it could not be correctly solved for that value

Comment: @M.M yes absolutely. Do you know if there is a faster way to compute ? I mean an other algorithm ?